# Cannot open Database using UNC path in Windows

Tags: orientdb

OrientDB Version 2.1.8 GA. Database URL with UNC path is not supported:

Here is simple program to demonstrate error:

```
public class ConnectionString
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String url = "plocal:\\\\srv\\db\\Database";
    ODatabaseDocumentTx db = null;

    try
    {
      db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(url).open("admin", "admin");
      System.out.println("Database is opened");
    }
    finally
    {
      if(db != null)
        db.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Debugging this code to the method `loadStorage(String iURL)` in the class com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient:

```
  public OStorage loadStorage(String iURL) {
// iURL = "plocal://srv/db/Database" OK
    if (iURL == null || iURL.length() == 0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("URL missed");

    if (iURL.endsWith("/"))
      iURL = iURL.substring(0, iURL.length() - 1);

// This code comes too early. Engine prefix is not yet removed from the iURL    

    if (isWindowsOS()) {
      // WINDOWS ONLY: REMOVE DOUBLE SLASHES NOT AS PREFIX (WINDOWS PATH COULD NEED STARTING FOR "\\". EXAMPLE: "\\mydrive\db"). AT
      // THIS LEVEL BACKSLASHES ARRIVES AS SLASHES
      iURL = iURL.charAt(0) + iURL.substring(1).replace("//", "/");
// After that statement iURL = "plocal:/srv/db/Database" UNC prefix is lost!
    } else
      // REMOVE ANY //
      iURL = iURL.replace("//", "/");

    // SEARCH FOR ENGINE
    int pos = iURL.indexOf(':');
    if (pos <= 0)
      throw new OConfigurationException("Error in database URL: the engine was not specified. Syntax is: " + URL_SYNTAX
          + ". URL was: " + iURL);
```

And a bit later we get an expected exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open local storage '/srv/db/Database' with mode=rw
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.open(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:248)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.open(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:252)
at com.riag.test.dbengine.skin.orientdb.ConnectionString.main(ConnectionString.java:22)
```

Comment: Can you use `plocal://srv/db/Database` ?

Comment: No help. Actually in loadStorage() method iURL already comes converted into the forward slash format. Problem is that special Windows handling comes too early when "plocal:" prefix is not yet removed from the URL So fist character in the URL is "p" and not "/".

Comment: I have opened an issue [in the issue tracker #5563](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5563) and posted a patch that fixes the problem. Somehow nobody noticed it.